# Android paging library test with Robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-recyclerview, reactive-programming, robolectric

Hy ! :)
Someone has any idea how can i test [Paging Library by Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) implementation with recyclerview ? My implementation is same to: [Example Pagig lib impl.](https://github.com/Ahmed-Abdelmeged/PagingLibraryWithRxJava)